# Como deixar oculto outra janela do programa?

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um programa que abre outros processos no computador para seu funcionamento, porém, dependendo da forma a ser utilizada pelo usuário, muitas janelas serão abertas desnecessariamente.

Como ocultar essas janelas, igualmente, não aparecerem na barra de tarefa.

Obs.: As janelas são do prompt do windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não acho adequado abrir outro programa através de uma chamada `system`. No Windows, você pode criar um novo processo através da chamada de sistema `CreateProcess()` após incluir o cabeçalho `windows.h`; Já no Linux, você pode fazer um `fork()` e em sequência um `execve()`.

Comment: realmente muito melhor!!

Answer (score 0):

Por citar prompt na pergunta, entendo que os processos estão sendo chamados via comando, se for o caso, poderia chamar para execução em segundo plano:

```
start "" /b nome_executavel.exe 

system("start "" /b nome_executavel.exe");
```